# How can I manage computers using my Firefox Sync account?

Tags: firefox, sync

I`m using Firefox Sync on a bunch of computers.

*I would like to manage my account, by removing some computers*. I can't find the place to do this, it should be on the Firefox Sync page, but the official page only has the privacy and download information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I remove a non-existent/lost device from firefox sync?](http://superuser.com/questions/267413/how-can-i-remove-a-non-existent-lost-device-from-firefox-sync)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Fire​fox ​Sync**​ lets​ you ​take​ all ​your​ Fire​fox ​data​
>   (such​ as your​ book​mark​s, history, pass​word​s and ​open​ tabs​) with​ you wherever​ you ​go.
>    You ​​just set up ​Fire​fox ​Sync​ on your​ **main** home computer​ and your​ Fire​fox ​data​ will​ be securely​ stored on Mozilla's ​servers ​and ​synchronized automatically from​ then​ on.
>   Then, when you set up Firefox Sync on your work computer (or even​ your​ phone running ​Fire​fox), your​ Firefox ​data​ will be automatically synchronized​ with​ your​ **main** home​ computer​.

There is no removing computer from the account manager.
If you want to manage the computers that synchronize with your **main** computer just remove **FireFox Sync** from **Firefox Addons**
on those computers and they will not synchronize automatically anymore.

More information to Mozilla Firefox support Site: [How to sync Firefox settings between computers](http://mzl.la/1xKtipV)

Answer (score 2):

From this Mozilla Support [thread](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/721484) :

> Simply sync all your computers, then
>   go into the Weave settings, and hit
>   the button that says roughly: "reset
>   all computers with this computer's
>   data."
>
> After that, the other computers will
>   be removed from the tab list, and
>   you'll be pretty much all set.

Answer (score 1):

[Try this advice site](http://lirent.net/firefox/how-to-set-up-firefox-sync-step-by-step.html)  out-for beta-4 but should work.

- Click on the firefox options tab not sync.
- To manage your Firefox Sync account go to Firefox-> options and on the last tab you will find Sync.
- From Sync Tab you can change account, DELETE DEVICE 
  or change preferences.
- From-Second Step: Connect with Firefox Sync-at bottom of page on this site

Comment: Anonymous comment: There is NO ACCOUNT tab or information in the new version. None. Not there. Nothing. No sync account management. No way to sync computers as it over and over just creates new account.