# Ban a stolen device from Firefox Sync

Tags: firefox, passwords, android, password-recovery, firefox-sync

I have my Firefox Passwords synced to my android tablet device.

Now that device got stolen, and I am not sure, if i had really set a masterpassword on the stored passwords there. Can I somehow delete the Passwords on that device?

I got some hints here: [How can I remove a non-existent/lost device from firefox sync?](https://superuser.com/questions/267413/how-can-i-remove-a-non-existent-lost-device-from-firefox-sync)

But I am not sure how to do it right in my case.

Here is a description how to [delete all sync data](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/how-do-i-manage-my-firefox-sync-account#w_how-do-i-clear-my-sync-data), but I guess, the other devices will not delete the data locally then, or would they?

Here is an article in the [firefox support forum](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-firefox-sync-lost-phone-or-tablet?esab=a&s=stolen%20sync%20data&r=5&as=s):

> **Disable Firefox Sync on a lost phone or tablet**
>
> So you've just lost your device (sorry about that) and you realize
>   you've been using Firefox Sync to get all of your usernames and
>   passwords on it. This article describes what you should do to prevent
>   someone from accessing your passwords.
>
> **First, change your sync password from a synced computer**
>
> This first step will prevent your lost phone from connecting to the
>   sync server and getting all of the new passwords that you will have to
>   create.
>
> **Second, change all of your account passwords from a synced computer**
>   ...

But i think this is **not a good solution**: There must be a better solution than changing all my passwords. (I for example have hundredths of passwords for lots of forums and blogs in it).

Maybe a better way would be to change all passwords to something nonsense and then synchronize those wrong passwords to the stolen tablet once it goes online. But that would be a lot of work too.

The best solution would be to delete all passwords in my sync-account but not the account itself, so the device will get an empty passwordlist at the next sync

I would export all passwords locally with the [Password Exporter Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/password-exporter/)

Comment: I filed this in the Mozilla bugtracker [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=881177) and [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=881175)

Answer (score 0):

once the passwords are on your stolen device, they must be considered compromised. deleting them at next sync is not enough, because as a clever thief i would block syncing and extract all passwords before you get a chance to remove them.

in other words: there is no better solution.